# Banach Decomposition Theorem from Fixpoint Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set. Knowing that every monotone set function $F: \mathcal{P}(A)\to\mathcal{P}(A)$ (in the sense that $X\subseteq Y\subseteq A\implies F(X)\subseteq F(Y)$) has a fixpoint, prove the Banach Decomposition Theorem:
Let $X,Y$ be sets and $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ arbitrary functions. Then there are disjoint decompositions $X=X_1\cup X_2$ and $Y=Y_1\cup Y_2$ such that $f[X_1]=Y_1$ and $g[Y_2]=X_2$. Hint: apply the monotone fixpoint theorem to $F(S)=X-g[Y-f[S]] $.

Now, I have been able to prove that $F: \mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ defined as above is monotone, so it has a fixpoint, call it $S$. Therefore:
$$ S=X-g[Y-f[S]]\implies X=S\cup g[Y-f[S]]\implies X=X_1\cup X_2 \ \text{with} \ X_1=S,X_2=g[Y-f[S]]$$
(Easy to check that $X_1\cap X_2=\varnothing$.)
Now, to find a decomposition for $Y$, what I did is:
$$X-S=g[Y-f[S]]\implies g^{-1}[X-S]=Y-f[S]\implies Y=Y_1\cup Y_2=f[S]\cup g^{-1}[X-S] $$
I am not sure about that last step. First, can I apply $g^{-1}$? Since $g$ is an arbitrary function, its inverse need not be a function (in principle only a relation). Also, I am pretty sure $g^{-1}[g[Y-f[S]]]\neq Y-f[S]$ in general. How can I proceed otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $X_1:=S$, $X_2:=X-S$ and $Y_1:=f[S]$, $Y_2:=Y-f[S]$ (which are disjoint decompostions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively).
Now $f[X_1]=f[S]=Y_1$ and
$$
g[Y_2]=g[Y-f[S]]=X-S = X_2.
$$

Comment: Great! That was way easier, thank you. Now, I want to check that I've proven the monotonicity of $F$ correctly: $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq X\implies f[S_1]\subseteq f[S_2]\implies Y-f[S_2]\subseteq Y-f[S_1]\implies ... \implies X-g[Y-f[S_1]]\subseteq X-g[Y-f[S_2]]$ Is that correct, are those implications true for arbitrary functions $f,g$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. $A\mapsto h[A]$ is increasing wrt $\subseteq$ for each function $h$ and the operation "complement" is decreasing wrt $\subseteq$.

Comment: Perfect! I just have one last question regarding this problem: I've been asked to deduce the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem from the Banach Decomposition Theorem. My reasoning: $|X|\leq |Y|,|Y|\leq |X|\implies \exists f:X\to Y, g:Y\to X$ injective. Then we use Banach and get easily (I think) that $f|_{X_1}:X_1\to Y_1$ and $g^{-1}|_{X_2}:X_2\to Y_2$ are bijective. Then we can define $h=f\cup g^{-1}$, or $f(x)$ if $x\in X_1$, and $g^{-1}(x)$ if $x\in X_2$, which is clearly bijective and hence $|X|=|Y|$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct to me.